# PySNMP high-level async get strange/slow behavior

Tags: python, pysnmp

Here is my pysnmp package info:

```
$ pip show pysnmp
---
Name: pysnmp
Version: 4.2.5
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: pyasn1, pycrypto
```

I have a not very complex program, following the "[Asynchronous GET Command Generator](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/cmdgen/get-async-multiple-transports-and-protocols.html)" example but extended so that this is done to 128 IP "targets" in a batch before the runDispatcher():

```
transportTarget = cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161), timeout=0.2, retries=2)
cmdGen.getCmd(
        authData, transportTarget, varNames,
        # User-space callback function and its context
        (cbFun, (authData, transportTarget)),
        lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True
    )
```

---

```
cmdGen.snmpEngine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
```

In my test run, the program started with what I'd expect: Added 128 targets, sent out requests, then 1~2 seconds later, it comes back either with responses, errors, and/or timeouts. But over time, it seems to "hang" after a batch of requests are sent out: It could sit there for 15 to 18 minutes although sometimes it still comes back within 2 seconds.

I do not expect the program to behave this way since I am using UDP. Are there anything in PySNMP I don't know that I need to cleanup?

Comment: Could you try your code with the latest pysnmp: http://pysnmp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pysnmp/pysnmp/?view=tar ? If this issue persists, please enable pysnmp debugging and send me the output at the moment when you think it is hanging.